# pyinstaller build error or not run script

Tags: python, pyinstaller

all

i have one python file,now i want use pyinstaller to build bin file,but pyinstall report this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pyi-build", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/cliutils/build.py", line 37, in run
    PyInstaller.build.main(None, args[0], **opts.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/build.py", line 1924, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/build.py", line 1873, in build
    execfile(spec)
  File "linux_server_script.spec", line 6, in <module>
    runtime_hooks=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/build.py", line 446, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/build.py", line 309, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/build.py", line 677, in assemble
    self._check_python_library(binaries)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/build.py", line 727, in _check_python_library
    raise IOError("Python library not found!")
IOError: Python library not found!
```

my python fisrt build has no use --enable-shared，now i recompile python and add option "--enable-shared",i copy libpython*.so* to /usr/local/lib/,but the problem also.

if my export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib,can build success,but when i run script

[pyinstall@zixun-01 tmp]$ ./linux_server_script 
Error loading Python lib '/tmp/libpython2.7.so.1.0': /tmp/libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was python lib error

pls del python clean and rebuild python 2.7 use "./configure --enable-shared"

and use pyinstall option "-p /usr/local/lib" to build